# How to manage and group different frames in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

I've seen some good posts here about adding multiple *frames* inside **Tk  root** ( [tut_version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBUpjijYtCk) [stckovrflw_version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46161761/python-2-7-tkinter-multiple-frames-and-menu) ). But i've didn't seen any 
way of referencing the window that is currently active. After some digging into `dir(Tkinter. Tk)` and reading help for `tkraise` I understood that there is a figurative `stack` element to `Tk` ( which it may be 'Tk. frames' or something ).

Stack element for `python-2.x` and `python-3.x` is determined by *dictionary* which holds name of the frames which is then called by **tkraise** passing a key to the dictionary.

As I understood the most of software built like this is based upon *tkraise() and don't think about it*, but what happens when I need to pass an specific frame in a stack a data where each frame will processes it differently - like waveform and spectral analyser of wave signal?

---

Since it was pointed out to me that question isn't clear enough, I wanted to show an image of what I want to achieve. Depending on the scope of the GUI changes that affect frames aren't direct or linear - often needing to manipulate different frames at same time, frames that aren't in same position and can't be relied upon to be active at the same time.

[image: desired layout functionality]

- **Local change**  - change that happens when event is triggered that affect only 1 frame buffer.
- **Group change**  - change that happens when event is triggered that affect multiple frame buffers.
- **Global change** - change that affects whole global buffer, and therefore it influences an whole GUI.

In general this kind of layout would be done via UDP protocol, with each frame having unique address and then having server that routes to frame buffer/stack that it needs. That would however need an independant thread with server that would read/write to the buffers when client sends an request. But on this occasion, I wanted to take advantage on tkinter natural threading functionality and use threads to read/write to desired buffer states when event is triggered, and to do that I need to know where I can find my frame and its buffer.

Then frame class could preload frame buffer (which is smaller in size than global buffer) when it is displayed and any changes to the frame buffer would be able to remain local, influence another frame buffer or change global buffer.

*But all that hinders on the fact I can't call on specific buffer within frame to make changes to if i don't know ID of the frame.*

---

**How do I know which frame is on top in the stack ( since dictionary are not sorted python type )? And how to access specific frame in stack ?**

Comment: Please choose the appropriate tag for a question,  just `python` if it relates to both.  I have removed the `python-3x` tag since you are using `Tkinter` (it's `tkinter` in Python 3)

Comment: Please put back that tag, since i am doing this calculation in both versions py.2.7.15 and py3.6.5. Not to crowd the text i've only put syntax in 2.7 form.

Comment: possible quick work around - save the key of the last frame to call tkraise.

Comment: As for passing content to a specific frame, I assume when you want to pass the data you know which one it is to be passed to - why not access the frame from the dictionary and don't call tkraise if you don't want to bring it to foreground?

Comment: because i think it would be easier to load data to a frame, and then raise it when necessary, since `load data; raise a, raise b` should take less time to execute than, `load data, raise a; load data, raise b`. I find this code to have lag issues, compared to other way. And since some frames use same data and other don't... preloading accurate data seems as good way to do this time wise.

Comment: @10SecTom I've actually found a solution to this problem, but it crude. I relies to stored a Boolean value that corresponds to the key of the dictionary. But i think there are smarter ppl than me here, so there must be a way for someone that has found a better solution. I will post my answer if there isn't any answer after a while.

Comment: @Danilo There very well may be a quick way to check the frame in view, I would assume this is the case. But either way you will get an id and then know what frame is on top - it still wont be much cleaner than remembering the frame when you raise it (unless I am missing something).

Comment: The link shows a similar question and there is an alternative suggestion, along with simply remembering the tkraise'd widget - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702973/determine-which-tkinter-widget-is-on-top-or-visible

Comment: Hmm, quite similar... But not the same. When you want to influence a specific item in the list you would do that by calling `__setitem__` on index of list, on dict without key you can not know right position since dict isn't sorted. In this problem the link youve posted is part 1/3 from whole solution. Most valuable solution would be to convert 'frames' to ordered list.

Comment: I'm confused by what you're actually asking here. Do you want to know how to identify a frame in a window? For what purpose? How are the frames created and why can't you store a reference to them in a variable/list?

Comment: @EthanField. *Purpose* : lets say we have layered frames that do different operation on some data. Example would be statistic, graphing and table display of some data with minor changes. Statistic would grab same data, calculate whatever we need to measure with statistic, graphing would do similar for different part of data  with original data and change from statistic and table would just show it as a table.

Comment: Why: Well tkinter naturally uses threading to manipulate gui elements, and why now use that same threading to preload data to desired frame before it is loaded ? But to do that you need to know to which frame ad which part of the stack. That is as short as i can give it without getting too deep for my language skill.

Comment: @Danilo I still don't understand what you're trying to do? What is a layered frame? When you say preload data, do you mean that you want to preload widgets into a hidden frame? You also mention making use of threading in tkinter to pass data to a widget, I don't understand why? That is a fairly complex thing to do which can be accomplished much more easily without threading.

Comment: @EthanField I edited the question in hope to illustrate what i wanted. But to be respectful, **layered frames** are multiple `tk.Frame`s layered in stack formation that *tkinter* naturally uses. When i say **preload data**, i mean preload parts of global data base to frame specific buffers, widgets aren't in this case tied directly to data manipulation. **Use of threading in tkinter** I wan't to use its inner threading to take advantage of limited amount of threads that some machine has, by using existing and not generating new ones to maximise effect of threads.

Comment: *GUI threading* is (as far as i know it) necessary part of any gui, and Tkinter has imported `threading` to use on its own. By `import` avalanche I can't be sure how many threads are active on *tkinter* app, and I can't rely on the fact that user who would use my app has powerful enough machine to handle 4+ threads and manipulate ~40 Mb per frame stack , and ~200 Mb per global stack per milisecond for application I am writing. Instead of thread being tied to displayed frame I want for them to go briefly outside of displayed frame scope and change some other frame buffer.

Comment: You need to isolate this down to a specific issue. I still don't understand **explicitly** what I can help you with. Frame widgets in tkinter have an ID that is assigned to them, and you can store this value in a variable. Is that not what you need? And when you say layered frames, do you mean a frame widget that has a parent which is also a frame widget?

Comment: @EthanField I am betting it isn't fun asking following questions where it seems that there is dissonance between us - thank you for your time and patience. I haven't encountered the ID you mention, i did however encounter the dictionary key. Do we mean same thing ?  
  
When i say layered frames, to add to description above, i mean that multiple frames are part of `Tk/tk` root window.

Comment: Like switching the tabs in the browser, they are layered in that manner. What are contents of individual tabs it doesn't matter for this analogy. What i want is to transfer data from 1 tab to another. And when switching data from 1 tab to another, if data transferred affects larger scope (multiple other tabs) update those tabs as well, even if they are not displayed. This project currently has around 10 independant `*.py` files. I don't know how to be more specific and explicit about it, without dumpling all 10 files in here (due to inheritance).